# Show loading image on each api call till response comes in axios library globally

Tags: axios

Sometimes, when we call an api,it takes long time to respond so we prefer to show loading image till response come.
there is start and end event in ajax request to show loading image , I want same kind of stuff in axios.
I want to make it globally for each request in axios library for react.
please suggest me something for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
            import axios from 'axios';
            import loading from '../loading.gif' // relative path to image

            class Home extends Component {
                constructor() {
                    super()
                    this.state = {
                        time: null,
                        loading: true,
                        retJobs: []
                    }
                    this.getJobs();

                }

                getJobs() {


                    axios.get('http://example.com/getData.php')
                        .then(response => {
                            this.setState({retJobs: response.data});
                            console.log(response);

                            console.log(this.state.retJobs.results.length);
                            console.log(this.state.retJobs.results);
                            this.setState({
                                time: response.data.time,
                                loading: false
                            });
                        })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        });

                }


                render() {

                    let content;

                    if (this.state.loading) {
                        content = <img src={loading} alt="loading"/>// or another graceful content
                    } else {
                        content = <p className="jobCount">Found {this.state.retJobs.results.length} Jobs</p>;
                    }

                    return (


                        <div>
                            <h4>Home</h4>
                            <div className="App-intro">
                                <div className="container">
                                    <div className="row mainContent">
                                        <div className=" row mainContent">
                                            {content}
                                            {this.state.retJobs.results && this.state.retJobs.results.map(function (item, idx) {
                                                return <div key={idx} className="col-lg-12">
                                                    <div className="jobs">
                                                        <div className="row jobHeader">

                                                            <div className="col-lg-6">
                                                                <h1>{item.jobTitle}</h1>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div className="col-lg-6">
                                                                <h3>{item.locationName}</h3>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div className="row">

                                                            <div className="col-lg-2">
                                                                <h2>{item.employerName}</h2>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div className="col-lg-10">
                                                                <p>{item.jobDescription}</p>
                                                            </div>


                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            })}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                }
            }

            export default Home;
```

Comment: Im fairly new to react.js , I was looking for the same answer and found a way of doing this from here

Comment: https://www.robinwieruch.de/learn-react-before-using-redux/?utm_content=buffer9d1e9&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=buffer

Comment: Still analyzing and working out if this is the right way to do it, but it works for me for the time being, hope this helps

Comment: Please don't just post only codes. Please elaborate on the answer so that people know why and how this answer works.

Comment: Add to the state "time, "loading" React will propagate it to the child for you.

state

The state is a data structure that starts with a default value when a Component mounts. It may be mutated across time, mostly as a result of user events.

So as it mounts if it changes as it does when retJobs: [] <--- an empty arrray

Comment: Add to the state "time, "loading" React will propagate it to the child for you.

state

The state is a data structure that starts with a default value when a Component mounts. It may be mutated across time, mostly as a result of user events.

So as it mounts if it changes as it does when retJobs: [] <--- an empty array

So if Loading is true show image if not then "dont show image" load the data

best I can explain for now

Comment: Why did you post it in the comment? Edit the answer please!